# Problem with usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11

A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.
To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.
Note that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the properties is shown.

I can open the internet site and i can see the messages and so on but if i sent messages I didn't get answers and it seems to me is not sending out my messages. I don't understand why.

Comment: That message is a warning, not an error.

Comment: What do you mean by "if I sent message"? Are you trying to use the browser console as a chat room?

Comment: Yes is a chatroom

Comment: The chatroom was working 10 days ago but maybe with the new updates of windows 11 or of chrome too then the problems occur.